# Matlab: How to get a value from a sparse vector without the sparse data structure?

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, sparse-matrix

Suppose

```
>> hhh=sparse([],[],[],2^40,1);
>> hhh(7)=1;
>> a=hhh(7)
```

Please, note that `hhh(7)>0` and `1>0` have a large time difference in computation times.

> **How can I get only the value of `hhh(7)` to the variable `a` without the sparse data structure?**

**Example**

> **Input:** assignment with the number and the sparse data structure, wrong.
>
> ```
> a =
>
>    (1,1)        1
> ```
>
> **Goal:** assignment just with a number
>
> ```
> >> a=1
>
> a =
>
>      1
> ```

Comment: How about `a(1) = hhh(7);`?

Comment: @Floris it gets the sparse data structure that is not the goal, the goal is to get it the value without the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `full` to convert your partial matrix (matrix element), e.g. the element to be stored in *a*, to `mat`-type:

```
a = full(hhh(7))
```

Note that this will also work for other selections, such as

```
a = full(hhh(7:9))
```

The output would then be

```
a =
     1
     0
     0
```

Comment: Vector is of the size `2^40`, have you tested it?

Comment: `hhh(7)` should not be of size 2^40… it is a single element. I think this can work. More elegant than my solution.

Comment: Of course, you should not convert *hhh* to a full matrix.. ;-) Just the element. BTW: This will work even, if a is not initialized prior to usage as it is required for the answer of Floris.

Comment: Now I don't know where the problem is: the stdout shows only one element but when I do the `full(hhh(7))`, it requires a massive amount of time. Sure I got this working fast with this small example but not with a bit different example, I am trying reproduce it, taking some time.

Comment: I assume this difference in processing time is due to the access to the large structure (the sparse matrix) you are using. This will always be the same, no matter how you convert an element to store it somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know what your memory exactly looks like at the shown instant, however, a difference in access time may stem from a cached result once a command has been executed. This may not apply to the Debug-Mode you are using as shown in your video. After all, the type of access is the same.

Comment: Do you mean this? It states `"Too many elements"`, http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq3HY.png.

Comment: Not sure yet but `full(A(1))` may have solved my problem i.e. specifying an index and changing to full so not going through the whole vector. Testing... still.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign an expression to a variable, you will "inherit" all the properties of the expression (where possible). To prevent this, you need to assign to an *element* of a previously declared object. For example:

```
a = 0;
a(1) = hhh(7);
```

Now you should have

```
>> a
a =
      1
```

Comment: Is there any command to analyze the `hhh(7)`, shared a video in the other comment that shows a case with the equivalent stdouts but taking a massive amount of time and memory. Let us call the `hhh(7)` by A so

`>> a=0;a(1)=A
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
same.`, now found the err? No err with this `a=0;a(1)=A(1)` and `full(A)` taking a massive amount of time despite A has only one element.